# Sculpting doesn't work right

Tags: mesh, sculpting

Hey if i want sculpt something, there is one problem that i can't sculpt the left,right,front and back but top and bottom is going normal.
Can someone help?
[image]

Comment: Mirror options are visible on the screenshot, but there are Lock options of the sculpt brush for X, Y and Z axes, are they left untouched?